# An error occurred while starting the application. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer

Tags: c#

I am getting this error and it just shows when I update the project with .net5. HELP

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl': Failed to compare two elements in the array.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just change in the program.cs of the server
IHostBuilder
and put the IWebHost and the project run well